# How can I do cdo remapbil

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling

Can anyone to help me?

I am trying to use this command to interpolate my *netcdf* data into my *wrfinput_d01* .
I have used this:

```
cdo remapbil,NEW_GRID_DEF old-file.nc new-file.nc
```

but I receive this massage:

```
[****Warning (cdf_scan_var_attr) : Time must be the first dimension! 
Unsupported array structure, skipped variable wetland_CH4_emissions!
Warning (cdf_set_var) : Inconsistent variable definition for wetland_CH4_emissions!
cdo remapbil (Abort): No remappable grid found!****][1]
```

What shall I do?

Comment: you have not provided what NEW_GRID_DEF looks like. Please provide that and put your netCDF file on a public site so that it can be downloaded. Very difficult to support you without these two pieces of information.

Comment: I agree with @gansub that the problem most likely lies in the `NEW_GRID_DEF`. In addition, I think that this question could find an easy answer in the CDO users forum (https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/boards)

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: maybe the order of the dimension is wrong for your variable `wetland_CH4_emissions` or cdo recognizes a wrong dimension as time dimension. The dimension, which is unlimited, is recognized as `time` dimension. Thus, if you have an unlimited non-time dimension it might be recognized as time.

Comment: thank you very much for your response dears